# PL/SQL Array Default Null

Tags: plsql

I have a plsql procedure with an html form. The procedure that the submit calls will not always have all variables passed. I would usually put default null for these variables but default null is not working for arrays. Is there any way that I can default the arrays to empty or null to allow the submit to continue?

```
procedure p_process(
p_cc_no     varchar2,
p_pc_no     pc_tm_no_vacant_array, --DEFAULT NULL??
p_tm_name   name_title_array, --DEFAULT NULL??
p_tm_no     pc_tm_no_vacant_array, --DEFAULT NULL??
p_job_title name_title_array, --DEFAULT NULL??
p_status    status_hrs_shift_array, --DEFAULT NULL??
p_hrs_per_week  status_hrs_shift_array, --DEFAULT NULL??
p_shift     status_hrs_shift_array, --DEFAULT NULL??
p_open      open_delete_array, --DEFAULT NULL??
p_vacant    pc_tm_no_vacant_array, --DEFAULT NULL??
p_comments  long_array, --DEFAULT NULL??
p_delete    open_delete_array, --DEFAULT NULL??
p_orient    number default null,
p_ot        number default null,
p_buy       number default null) is
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a variable in a PL/SQL package specification that is never assigned a value.

e.g.

```
create package arraytype_pkg is
  null_pc_tm_no_vacant pc_tm_no_vacant_array;
  null_name_title name_title_array;
  ... etc. ...
end;
```

Then you can refer to these in your procedure signature:

```
procedure p_process(
p_cc_no     varchar2,
p_pc_no     pc_tm_no_vacant_array default arraytype_pkg.null_pc_tm_no_vacant,
p_tm_name   name_title_array default arraytype_pkg.null_name_title,
p_tm_no     pc_tm_no_vacant_array default arraytype_pkg.null_pc_tm_no_vacant,
p_job_title name_title_array default arraytype_pkg.null_name_title,
p_status    status_hrs_shift_array default arraytype_pkg.null_status_hrs_shift,
p_hrs_per_week  status_hrs_shift_array default arraytype_pkg.null_status_hrs_shift,
p_shift     status_hrs_shift_array default arraytype_pkg.null_status_hrs_shift,
p_open      open_delete_array default arraytype_pkg.null_open_delete,
p_vacant    pc_tm_no_vacant_array default arraytype_pkg.null_pc_tm_no_vacant,
p_comments  long_array default arraytype_pkg.null_long,
p_delete    open_delete_array default arraytype_pkg.null_open_delete,
p_orient    number default null,
p_ot        number default null,
p_buy       number default null) is
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the proceure is part of a package so you can create an overloaded version of the procedure. One version will have array as an input parameter whereas other will not. Based on the input parameters, oracle will automatically call correct procedure. Sometime this concept is also called wrappers.

"
Overloading Subprogram Names
PL/SQL lets you overload subprogram names and type methods. You can use the same name for several different subprograms as long as their formal parameters differ in number, order, or datatype family. For an example of an overloaded procedure in a package, see Example 9-3."

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#sthref1738

Answer (score -1):

If your procedure has not always all parameter passed, you can use named notation.
In named notation, the actual parameter is associated with the formal parameter using the arrow symbol (=>). The procedure call will be like the following:

```
execute p_process(
p_cc_no     => 'AAA',
p_orient    => 20,
p_job_title => 'BOSS'
);
```

Or you can use mixed notation (positional notation should precede the named notation):

```
execute p_process(
'AAA',
p_orient    => 20,
p_job_title => 'BOSS'
);
```

Search "PLSQL Methods for Passing Parameters" in the Internet.